# The running time of Clang and GCC8.3 for the same piece of code is inconsistent

Tags: gcc, time, clang, save

I modified a piece of code and then tested the running time. The code compiled by Clang has obvious time savings, but the code compiled by GCC8.3 does not save time, but theoretically there should be time savings.

I would like to ask if it is compiled by GCC8.3 caused by instability or other reasons.